# What is mysql_result in PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I have been looking all over for what i thought was very simple answer!
So very simple question, what would

```
$result = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT name FROM cars WHERE id = 3"), 0);
echo $result;
```

be In PDO?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: $pdo->query('SELECT name FROM cars WHERE id = 3 LIMIT 1')

Comment: mysql_result was evil thing in mysql, and there is no point in looking for it in pdo

Answer (score 5):

```
$result = $pdo->query('SELECT name FROM cars WHERE id = 3')->fetchColumn();
```

See [`PDO::query`](http://php.net/manual/pdo.query.php) and [`PDOStatement::fetchColumn`](http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)